# UNNotification: Custom Sound for LocalNotification is not playing in iOS10

Tags: ios, unnotificationrequest

I'm firing a local notification. Since `UILocalNotification` class is deprecated in iOS 10, I have used `UserNotifications.framework`.

When I try to set the custom sound for the notification, the default sound is playing all time.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)fireLocalNotification:(id)sender {
    
    UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello!" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello_message_body"
                                                         arguments:nil];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"sound.mp3"];
    
    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                  triggerWithTimeInterval:5 repeats:NO];
    
    UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecond"
                                                                          content:content trigger:trigger];
    
    // Schedule the notification.
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        
        if(!error){
            
            NSLog(@"Completion handler for notification");
        }
        
    }];
}
```

My sound is fine; sound.mp3 is present in project bundle itself.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter?language=objc

Comment: is that .mp3 file is added in you Project - Target - Copy Bundle Resources ?

Comment: yes, it is present in my bundle, and added in target -  Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Try deleting app from device, Clean and Run again app in device.

Comment: Strange but it worked..! Thanks..@Wolverine

Comment: I have updated my comment as answer. If it solves your problem, Please accept it as answer so it will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the app from the device, clean and run the app again on device.

Sometimes, resources are not properly updated; I think that is the problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Long audio-files are not supported.

Is your file longer then 30 seconds? If yes, it will not work. Only files shorter then 30 seconds are available. If the file is longer then 30 seconds then it will be replaced with default sound.

[UNNotificationSound documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound)

Comment: It is always helpful to provide a link to the documentation where you got that info from. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Comment: Thank you @KaiEngelhardt, I have aded it.