# What sound is UNNotificationSound.default()?

Tags: ios, audio, notifications

My iOS app uses the default notification sound:

```
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

I hear the sound called "Tri-Tone", even though that sound is not set anywhere in my settings panel Sounds view. I expect to hear the sound set for "Reminder Alerts". Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215838/unnotification-custom-sound-for-localnotification-is-not-playing-in-ios10)

Comment: I'm not trying to set a custom sound via an external resource, I simply want to change the default sound in the Settings Panel, but I always hear the same sound.

Comment: @user1930720 , have you identified the reason for such behavior? Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No, I haven't made any progress. I can't seem to get anything other than a single sound to occur.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound/1649030-default) it plays the *default sound for notifications*.

I don't think the system will let you change that default sound. If you are the developer of the App you have to provide your own sound file with you App.