# How can i set my recorded voice as notification sound in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to record my voice and set it as a sound in local notification payload. Please let me know if there is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Could this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215838/unnotification-custom-sound-for-localnotification-is-not-playing-in-ios10

Comment: In the question you shared, the sound.mp3 is present in project bundle itself but in my case its not present in application bundle. I need to somehow copy it and make it useful because I am storing the recording in the dataDirectory not in the application bundle.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of this (and the answer is "Not possible"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150806/uilocalnotification-playing-a-custom-audio-file-saved-in-documents-directory

Comment: It is possible, I am working on it. If I manage to copy the file or being able to save the recording in the Library/Sounds.

Comment: This seems to be true. I've retracted my close vote. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To play a recorded voice as notification sound you have to store the recorded voice data in Library/Sound/**Filename**

Please check attached screenshot of apple documments.

[image]